# Web page scraping: press javascript button

Tags: python, screen-scraping, wget

I am trying to scrape a web page and to recieve the data i need to press a button. This is the source code for the button:

"a class="press-me_btn" href="javascript:void( NewPage['DemoPage'].startDemo() );" id="js_press-me_btn">PRESS ME

Is it possible to "press" the button somehow without using a browser? either by using wget with the --post-data argument or maybe a small python, ruby, perl etc. application?

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In this case these is not a button, it is an [anchor element](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_a.asp), i think that you will need to run the js code, that is in the href attribute:

```
javascript:void( NewPage['DemoPage'].startDemo() );
```